# ASP.NET MVC tries to load older version of Owin assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, assemblies, asp.net-identity, owin

As a bit of context, I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses OAuth-based authentication via Microsoft's OWIN implementation, for Facebook and Google only at this stage. Currently (as of v3.0.0, git-commit 4932c2f), the `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` and `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions` don't provide any property to force Facebook nor Google respectively to reauthenticate users (via appending the appropriate query string parameters) when signing in.

Initially, I set out to override the following classes:

- `FacebookAuthenticationOptions`
- `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions`
- `FacebookAuthenticationHandler` (specifically `AuthenticateCoreAsync()`)
- `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler` (specifically `AuthenticateCoreAsync()`)

yet discovered that the `~AuthenticationHandler` classes are marked as `internal`.

So I pulled a copy of the source for the Katana project (http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) and modified the source accordingly.

After compiling, I found that there are several dependencies that needed updating in order to use these updated assemblies (**Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook** and **Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google**) in the MVC project:

- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Security
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
- Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb

This was done by replacing the existing project references to the 3.0.0 versions and updating those in web.config. Good news: the project compiles successfully.

In debugging, I received an exception on startup:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in [MVC web assembly].dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The underlying exception indicated that **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** was trying to load v2.1.0 of **Microsoft.Owin.Security** when calling `app.UseExternalSignInCookie()` from `Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` in Startup.Auth.cs.

Unfortunately that assembly (and its other dependency, **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin**) aren't part of the Project Katana solution, and I can't find any accessible repository for these assemblies online.

> Are the **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** assemblies open source, like the Katana project?
>   Is there a way to fool those assemblies to use the referenced v3.0.0 assemblies instead of v2.1.0? The `/bin` folder contains the 3.0.0 versions of the Owin assemblies.

I've upgraded the NuGet packages for **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin**, and this is still an issue.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you might need an assembly binding redirect.  Take a look at this as a guide: http://rionscode.wordpress.com/tag/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-owin/

Comment: Thanks, I read that and realised that the binding redirects it talks about are the changes I made in web.config: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />` I've checked and verified that the referenced assemblies are indeed 3.0.0.0, but the issue is still occurring.

Comment: @d_mcg - did you specify the assembly names in your binding redirect?  You will need a binding redirect for each package that you want to redirect to the proper version.  Also, did you actually update your references in your project or just replace the .dlls in your bin folder?

Comment: Yes - there are two binding redirects as follows: `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>` I also made sure that the project references were updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that while `FacebookAuthenticationHandler` is marked as `internal`, its abstract base class `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` is fortunately `public`. In the end, I took the modified version of `FacebookAuthenticationHandler` from the Katana project source, renamed it and included it in my own solution, so that it still uses the 2.1 libraries and doesn't cause problems with the other NuGet dependencies.

Likewise for `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler`.

So, using the Facebook example, I have the following class definitions in my MVC project:

```
// Overridden to add additional property 'ForceReauthentication'
public class FacebookOAuth2ExtendedOptions : FacebookAuthenticationOptions
...

// Reimplemented v2.1 source with modified method 'ApplyResponseChallengeAsync'
public class FacebookOAuth2CustomHandler : AuthenticationHandler<FacebookOAuth2ExtendedOptions>
...

// Reimplemented v2.1 source, modified to use 'FacebookOAuth2CustomHandler '
public class FacebookOAuth2CustomMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<FacebookOAuth2ExtendedOptions>
...
```

Finally in the `Startup` class (**App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs**), I register the authentication using my custom middleware classes:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...

    var fbOptions = new FacebookOAuth2ExtendedOptions()
    {
        AppId = facebookAppKey,
        AppSecret = facebookAppSecret,
        ForceReauthentication = true
    };
    app.Use(typeof(FacebookOAuth2CustomMiddleware), app, fbOptions);

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 10):

I updated to OWin 3.0.1 and that fixed the problem:

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

I searched for the references in the list (under NuGet.org) and installed new references for Microsoft.Owin as well as Microsoft.Owin.Security, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook etc.

I then checked the version number in my packages.config and Web.Config file and found that this had updated correctly:

Packages.config example:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" TargetFramework="net45" />
```

Web.Config example:

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
```