# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.0.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I had a solution that was running fine locally but upon deployment received this issue.  Upon searching stackoverflow I found several similar questions, the most popular one being [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072168/asp-net-mvc-tries-to-load-older-version-of-owin-assembly).

That post suggests updating several assemblies.  Using the NuGet package manager  I updated:

`Microsoft.Owin`

`Microsoft.Owin.Security`

`Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`

`Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`

I redeployed but it still doesn't work.

I'm confused because the current version of Owin is 3.0.1, which is what I have installed, not 3.0.0.0.   But apparently something is still trying to load 3.0.0.0.

EDIT: I guess I just had to delete all my previous files and reupload.  It's working now.

Comment: Did you checked your packages.config ? is it updated correctly ? and also web.confg

Comment: What should I be looking for in web.config?  I dont see any references to it

Comment: Based on your advice I tried to add the following       `<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: I deleted all previous files and republished and it worked

Comment: @apdm post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all previous files on my web hosting application (GoDaddy) and republished and it worked